# Why defined attribute value is not printing here?

Tags: python, oop, attributes, magic-methods

I've the following code:

```
class PageElement:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.x = b

    @property
    def prop(self):
        print(f"{self.x}")
        return 1

class Tag(PageElement):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __getattr__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print("Tag.getattr was invoked")

t = Tag(3, 4)
print(t.prop)
```

it outputs

```
Tag.getattr was invoked
None
1
```

I checked `t.__dict__` to be `{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'x': 'x'}`, but still the value of `t.x (='x')` is not printed when `print(f"{self.x}")` is executed in the source code. I can't understand how on Earth `f"{self.x}"` is getting evaluated to `None`. Kindly help.

Comment: In `Tag.__init__` you don't call the `__init__` method of the super class.

Comment: @Matthias I don't think I'm calling `__init__` method of the super there?

Comment: @NeoAnderson That's exactly the problem, plus that the argument that `__getattr__` receives is the name of the attribute, not its value, so `self.x = x` is not doing what you think it is doing anyway

Comment: `__getattr__` should return a value. At the moment it returns an implicit `None` and that `None` is printed in `print(f"{self.x}")`.

Comment: @DeepSpace Why do I need to call the `__init__` of super in `Tag` when I can define an object of type `Tag` independent of the code contained in it's parent class? Isn't it the case that methods of parent classes are called only when same name methods are not defined in the the class the instance belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **init** of PageElement (SuperClass), when you try to print

```
print(f"{self.x}")
```

Your self.x is undefined because you don't call constructor of SuperClass (PageElement). You can add this call to SubClass (Tag)

```
class PageElement:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.x = b

    @property
    def prop(self):
        print(f"{self.x}")
        return 1


class Tag (PageElement):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        super().__init__(self.a, self.b)

    def __getattr__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print("Tag.getattr was invoked")


t = Tag(3, 4)
print(t.prop)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that several misconceptions about [Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) are involved here.

- `__getattr__` should return an attribute. In this code it assigns the named of the accessed attribute (the argument that it receives) to the `x` attribute
- `__getattr__` is only being called when the accessed attribute does **not** exist on the instance
- Subclasses should almost always explicitly call the parent's class `__init__` method.

Due the first 2 points, any subsequent calls to `Tag.prop` **will** in fact output `x`:

```py
t = Tag(3, 4)
print(t.prop)
print(t.prop)
```

outputs

```
Tag.getattr was invoked
None
1
x
1
```

This is because on the first call to `t.prop`, `x` does not exist on `t` (because `PageElement.__init__` was never called). This triggers the call to `Tag.__getattr__` that assigns `x` but never returns it. This is where the `None` comes from.

On the second call to `t.prop`, `x` does exist so `__getattr__` is not called (so `None` is not returned from any where). Because `x` does exist now, `prop` can print it and it prints `x`.

All of this is unnecessarily over-engineered , and instead you should just be calling `PageElement.__init__` from `Tag.__init__`:

```py
class PageElement:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.x = b

    @property
    def prop(self):
        print(f"{self.x}")
        return 1

class Tag(PageElement):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a, b)

t = Tag(3, 4)
print(t.prop)
```

This outputs

```
4
1
```

Comment: Actually, it seems that "\_\_getattr__ is only being called when the accessed attribute does not exist on the instance **and** `type(instance)` & it's base classes don't have any property with the same name as the attribute."
Since `prop` here is also the name of a `property` in the super class, so the debugger tells me that it is called first (if it was any other name `Tag.__getattr__` had been called as you described).

Comment: You can find this in the documentation of [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__): "Called when the default attribute access fails with an `AttributeError` (either `__getattribute__()` raises an `AttributeError` because _name_ is not an instance attribute or an attribute in the class tree for `self`; or `__get__()` of a _name_ property raises `AttributeError`). This method should either return the (computed) attribute value or raise an `AttributeError` exception."